# JQuerymobile How to Remove Row Space Between Input Fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using Cordova/JQuery Mobile

I am trying to develop a settings page with multiple input fields. I would to like remove the spacing between the rows but I am unable to find any solution.

[image]

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="container">

                        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="SettingsCat0" />
                        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="SettingsCat1" />
                        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="SettingsCat2" />
                        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="SettingsCat3" />
                        <input type="text" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" id="SettingsCat4" />

</div>
```

And here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bRszY/158/)

Comment: Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/bRszY/159/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS rule in your html or in a CSS file that gets loaded after the jQuery one:

```
input.ui-input-text.ui-mini, textarea.ui-input-text.ui-mini, .ui-input-search.ui-mini, div.ui-input-text.ui-mini {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks
I wonder if there is a way to remove those shades between the fields.

Comment: .ui-shadow-inset {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}